# How to combine multiple GitLab rules with And?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

According to the documentation, multiple rules are being combined with `OR` operation, and indeed it behaves that way. But I have a specific situation.

So I have a set of jobs that are used for `PCF` platform and another set for `Kubernetes` platform. They are managed simply by setting variables. And it is possible that we may need both to be active:

```yaml
.pcf-platform:
  rules:
    - if: $PLATFORM_PCF == "true"

.k8s-platform:
  rules:
    - if: $PLATFORM_K8S == "true"

.manual-feature-branch-optional:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true

.manual-default-branch-optional:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule"
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true
```

Now we imagine we have these jobs:

```yaml
deploy-dev-pcf:
  extends:
    - .manual-feature-branch-optional
    - .pcf-platform
  script:
    - do deploy

deploy-dev-k8s:
  extends:
    - .manual-feature-branch-optional
    - .k8s-platform
  script:
    - do deploy

deploy-prod-pcf:
  extends:
    - .manual-default-branch-optional
    - .pcf-platform
  script:
    - do deploy
```

Now, imagine both `PLATFORM_K8S` and `PLATFORM_PCF` are set to `true` and the current branch is a feature branch (not default); as expected, both `deploy-dev-pcf` and `deploy-dev-k8s` are added to the pipeline but so as `deploy-prod-pcf`.

It seems the first rule that checks `if the current branch is default branch` is resolved to `false` but then it evaluates the next rule that checks `PLATFORM_PCF equals to true` and since it is true it adds the job while we are still in a feature branch.

I need to somehow make these two separate rules being `And`-ed so I can turn on/off jobs depending on the desired platform as well as the type of branch.

I could create one set of rules for `Kubernetes` and one set for `PCF` but that increases the number of rules unreasonably and I am reluctant to that approach.

In the documentation it is saying that `only` clauses are being evaluated with `And` but it seems `only` is being deprecated in favour of `rules`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get this right, you'll need to understand:

- How jobs are merged together; and
- How rules are evaluated

Or you can just skip to the last heading for your answer :-)

### How jobs are merged together

Part of your problem here seems to be your expectation of what `extends:` does in this case. When array values meet through `extends:`, they override one another and do not combine. See [merge details](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#merge-details) for additional context.

For example, given this configuration:

```yaml
.foo:
  rules:
    - if: $FOO == "foo"

.bar:
  rules:
    - if: $BAR == "bar"
job:
  extends:
    - foo
    - bar  # array of rules here will override the previous declarations
```

In other words, only one set of those rules will be effective in the resulting configuration in this case, as if written like so:

```yaml
job:
  rules:
    - if: $BAR == "bar"
```

So, in your example, only the platform rule is being applied, which results in the behavior you are observing.

One way to get around this is to use `!reference` instead to build your rules array:

```yaml
rules:
  - !reference [.foo, rules]
  - !reference [.bar, rules]
```

### How rules are evaluated

Another aspect that needs understanding here is how rules are evaluated. GitLab will evaluate each rule in order and stop at the first rule that evaluates true. There can be *at most*, one rule that takes effect! If no rules match, the job is excluded from the pipeline.

So, there are a couple ways you can get the effect of `AND` evaluation.

You can combine it into a single rule and combine with `&&` operators:

```
rules:
  - if: $FOO == "foo" && $BAR == "bar"
```

You can also get the effect you want by ordering different rules in a particular order and using the inverse logic combined with `when: never`. For example, these rules have the same effect as above:

```
rules:
  - if: $FOO != "foo"
    when: never
  - if: $BAR != "bar"
    when: never
  - when: on_success  # base case is important!
```

Inverting the logic here (checking `!=` instead of `==`), we allow evaluation to continue to subsequent rules. This is important if you want to define and re-use rules separately.

### In practice

Applying the understandings explained above, using your example, you might do something like this which allows you to define each rule just once:

```yaml
# define different sets of rules
.rules:
  pcf-only:
    - if: $PCF_PLATFORM != "true"
      when: never
  k8s-only:
    - if: $K8S_PLATFORM != "true"
      when: never
  manual-feature-branch-optional:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true

# Combine these rules in different ways that can be reused
.k8s-deploy:
  rules: # Order matters!
    - !reference [.rules, k8s-only]
    - !reference [.rules, manual-feature-branch-optional]

.pcf-deploy:
  rules:
    - !reference [.rules, pcf-only]
    - !reference [.rules, manual-feature-branch-optional]

# Use `extends:` for each combination of rules as-needed
deploy-dev-pcf:
  extends:
    - .pcf-deploy  
  script:
    - do deploy

# alternatively, you can define rules directly instead of using `extends:`
deploy-dev-k8s:
  rules:
    - !reference [.rules, k8s-only]
    - !reference [.rules, manual-feature-branch-optional]
  script:
    - do deploy

# ... and so on
```

There's probably other refactoring opportunities for you here, but that's perhaps beside the point of the question :)

Comment: Thanks heaps! I will implement this and see how it goes but I am also keen to know what other refactoring you are suggesting.

Comment: Great... tested it and worked. Your explanation of how the evaluation works helped a lot as I needed to make some more adjustments. I've been going through the GitLab doco they are very brief and not explaining what exactly is happening. Thanks again and I appreciate if there is any more refactoring point you have for my approach.

Comment: @xbmono as far as other opportunities for refactoring, mainly my thought was you might be able to orient everything into a [matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) with two dimensions: platform and environment (e.g. pcf/k8s and dev/production). But I suppose it depends on details of your scripts and what you want, exactly. You could maybe also avoid repeating the same `script:` (assuming it's actually the same or could be the same for each job).

Comment: This is better than the Gitlab docs to explain how rules are evaluated!